# Can yagnopaveet worn on hand temporarily?

Tags: yagnopavitam, upanayanam

Yagnopaveet or sacred thread should never be removed from the body, but can it be temporarily worn on hand for purposes like medical checkup, swimming, or photoshoots for the time being like an hour or two?